# Can't get click event of UIButton (Programatically Created)

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have created 1 view that is having one subview and 2 buttons and 1 label.

Buttons and label added into the view with tag.

Outside access button, and i got button tag but click event not performed.

```
let imgView = UIButton()
let image = UIImage(named: "photo-about-reelsonar") as UIImage?
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = true
imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imgView.tag = 156
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imgView.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Added into view.

```
catchView.addSubview(imgView)
```

Getting button.

Function to create that view:

```
let view = createCatchImgView(imgSize)

if let btn = view.viewWithTag(156) as? UIButton {
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CatchFeedVC.btnClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: Please add your full code because this is very confusing.

Comment: No one knows what `createCatchImgView()` does. Add relevant code, if you want relevant help.